# How to write a conditions when a value from drop down is selected with select_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to generate a report where there are 3 static values in a drop down,  where when we select one value and click on submit, the code of this value has to be generated.

This is my reports controller:

```
  def create_report
    @report = MyReport.create_report(params[:id], params.merge(account: current_account, user: current_user))
    @report.execute
  end
```

In app/views/reports/report/_report.html.haml:

```
= content_for :report_filters do
  .form-group
    = select_tag :param_name, options_for_select([['A data', 'A'], ['B data', 'B']], params[:param_name])
```

This is my .rb file in app/reports folder:

```
class TransactionReport < MyReport
  def execute
    @items = []
    if params[:param_name] == "A"
       daily_items = A.by_account(@account).active.includes(:company_name, :emp_name, :address).where('date(txn_date) = ? ', current_date)
      @items << Item.new(items: daily_items, date: current_date) unless daily_items.empty?
    elsif params[:param_name] == "B"
      daily_items = B.by_account(@account).active.includes(:company_name, :emp_name, :primary_sales_rep).where('date(txn_date) = ? ', current_date)
    end
  end
end
```

It displaying error as:

*undefined local variable or method `params' for #*

Please tell me how to write if sattement if A is selected or B or C without using Javascript..

Comment: A few thoughts.  `params` is only available in the controller, you would have to pass those into your report method.  Second thought:  You are creating a `MyReport` but you are showing the code from `TransactionReport`

Comment: TransactionReport inherits from MyReport. It is working fine any one of A, B, C with simple execute method mentioned above. Please tell me the case if A is selected or B or C.

Comment: @danielrsmith - is there any way?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Like I said the method `params` is only defined in the controller.  You would need to pass it to your report to have access to it.